# Making Save and Load Windows using SDL

Tags: c++, game-design, sdl2

I've been working on a world builder project recently and I've finished most of the work but there is just one thing I can't think of how to do.

For example in a strategy game's world builder when you want to save a map and click the save button a window pops up and you can enter a name you want and save the map with that name, or overwrite a map you can chose by clicking one of the pre-saved maps in the list in the window. Or load a map again by clicking a map name in a load window.

How can I render a text while I'm writing it with SDL 2.0.3(when you're saving a map you need to see the name you give) and save that file with that name and also show other save files' names in a list?Is there a way to do it with SDL_ttf library or should I use bitmapfonts?

How can I decide if I want to overwrite a map or create a new one (I need to overwrite a map when it's name is clicked and create a new one when the bar to write the new map's name is clicked)?

In the load menu how can I load the specific save file I've chosen?

And just one more question: I'm currently writing the save data in a .txt file, is there a better way of doing that that you suggest?

I'm using SDL with C++.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have many questions. Please decide on one at a time. Are you asking about how to render text in SDL, about how to serialise/deserialise game data, or how to write to or read from files using SDL?

Comment: I know how to write or read from a file. I just don't know how to read a specific file among a number of files and rendering text at the moment I'm writing it and give that name to the save file.

Comment: on sourceforge, tiny file dialogs offers several modal function calls. it's a simple C C++ cross-platform file to add to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL doesn't provide typical App GUI affordances.

(It *does* have `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox()` and `SDL_ShowMessageBox()` which are probably only useful for reporting a startup error or a crash, or system advisories.)

You could either mix-in some platform-specific bits as @wondra suggests (quick and done!), or use an abstraction layer which caters more specifically to higher level application work, such as Juce, Qt, or wxwidget.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145910/cross-platform-native-open-save-file-dialogs

Or roll your own on top of OpenGL; chances are you've done some of that already for other GUI elements in your game/editor. Text entry & display is a little harder than a button, but still, just more of the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289447/using-sdl-ttf-with-opengl discusses how to render text with a ttf font onto an SDL_Surface, which you can then put onto your window. (There's many other ways to render text, that's just one approach.)

(As for the P.S. question, sure, text files are great, you can read & edit them. Win!)

Comment: I'm rendering texts on buttons but how can I render the text at the moment I'm writing it with SDL_ttf?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use OpenGl library that does not implement open/save file dialog, you can avoid a lot of work(rendering text, folder browsing etc.) by using [platform-specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167286/win32-function-to-openfiledialog) as your editor will likely run on single system anyway. Just ask you OS do it - quick, "cheap" and easy. Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948783/c-simple-open-file-dialog-in-linux) for linux.

Comment: As pointed by Anko, you should separate those two questions, however .txt files are depending on size of your project fine optionally you can just change extension to .data or something.